# Почему всегда возвращает TRUE?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

```
TestApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {

  $http.post('test.php')
        .success(function(data){
          console.log(data)
        })
        .error(function(data,status){
          console.log('error');
        })

}])
```

test.php

```
<?php

echo false;
```

Comment: Где конкретно вам померещилось TRUE? Единственный положильный результат, который может вернуть ваш сниппет - callback SUCCESS

Comment: если я в success пишу так
.success(function(data){
          console.log('ок')
        })
то оно всегда в консоле пишит ок

Comment: Довольно странный способ вернуть результат )) Сейчас напишу решение

Answer (score 1):

Ты скорее всего имеешь ввиду, что всегда  success, зайди в хромовский дебагер там в network  будет ответ сервера, так как запрос прошел успешно-то data.result == SUCCESS по этому и true.

Answer (score 1):

- **beforeSend** происходит непосредственно перед отправкой запроса на сервер.
- **error** происходит в случае неудачного выполнения запроса.
- **dataFilter** происходит в момент прибытия данных с сервера. Позволяет обработать "сырые" данные, присланные сервером.
- **success** происходит в случае удачного завершения запроса.
- **complete** происходит в случае любого завершения запроса.

Answer (score 0):

`test.php` это серверный скрипт и вернуть `false` указанным способом нельзя, тк ответ остается на сервере. Для передачи информации на браузер клиента нужно оформить его в формате JSON ну или просто текстом что то отправить. Ниже написан пример возвращения JSON

```php
<?php

echo json_encode(['result' => false]);
```

Если же речь идет об ошибке сервера, которую надо отправить на клиента, то стоит использовать такой вариант

```php
<?php

http_response_code(404); // 404 - вариант кода ошибки
```